# Dynamic Cell / Column in if formular

Tags: google-sheets

I want to build a list with textjoin() in my google sheet, but depending on a certain value in a cell, that will change from time to time.

My formular so far looks like this

```
=TEXTJOIN(char(10);TRUE;
  if(ON10=1;VLOOKUP(P10;rawdata!$B$2:$BX$62;2;false);"");
  if(ON11=1;VLOOKUP(P11;rawdata!$B$2:$BX$62;2;false);"");
  if(ON12=1;VLOOKUP(P12;rawdata!$B$2:$BX$62;2;false);"");
...
)
```

that works fine and does what I need, but my problem is, that the cells "ON10" and "ON11" etc will change. It will be "OV10", "PD10" and so on.. so the "gap" or interval will allways be the same.

is there a way to make that part of the formular dynamic?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Would you be able to share a sample of your sheet/data with an example of your desired output?

Comment: i made a copy and stripped it a little: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1By2Y-leCWgT5ScxiX2egenWuTIVxgqoUqcr61biuQKo/edit?usp=sharing

on the "Setup"-Sheet in the red square is what i want as an output. Its just a vlookup to the rawdata sheet to get nicknames (its for a world of warcraft guild). 

on the setup sheet, the lighter green cells are the ones, that should determine if the nickname appears in the output list or not. so basically, what i need is a way to quickly change the light green columns (in the formular, ON10, ON11, etc) to get the list for the next day and so on

Comment: Based on the sample table you have provided, I think this is possible using [Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). My idea of approach is to get the cell value of your desired column and run the vlookup formula through apps script.

Comment: didnt think about that, will try :) thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

Reposting comment:

I'd recommend using [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) to set a dynamic range of columns. You can also read more about [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) to utilize cells depending on the condition (in your case, use getValue to create conditions based on the cell value)